# Multiple catch blocks fail in throwing method

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Currently, I have the following method

And another method simplified to the following:

```
suspend fun <T> handleRequest(
  requestCaller: suspend() -> Response<T>
): Result<Something, T> {
  return try {
    requestCaller.invoke()
  } catch(ioException: IOException) {
  } catch(exception: Exception) {
  } 
}
```

When I call the above method and `requestCaller.invoke()` and throw `IllegalStateException`, the exception is NOT caught at all.

However, when I remove the first catch block that catches `IOException`, it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an error to throw an exception in an interceptor, unless it is an IOException. This is enforced in Java (which has checked exceptions) but not Kotlin (no checked exceptions).

If you throw an IOException, it’ll propagate back to your callsite. If you throw any other exception type your call will be canceled and your exception will be delivered to the current thread’s uncaught exception handler.